# sublimetext: using regular expression for replacing string

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I'm trying to clean up an long CSV file using SublimeText instead of Excel.

I've created a RegExp which use some greedy expression like

^.*somehting.com.au.*$

The search pattern works fine, but when it comes to the replacing everything with a blank string, Sublime return an error in the bottom bar I can barely read as it immediately disappears without anything happening.
I do suspect it's an error, and I have read something "too generic" rule or something.

Any help?

Comment: Try pressing ctrl + '. This will open up the console which should retain the errors you have been seeing.

Comment: How do you know your pattern works fine? Should you not escape dots like so? `^\.somehting\.com\.au\.$`

Comment: I know the pattern is working because I've asked sublime to highlight the text and this has been highlighted because of the match. Dots was escaped initially but it doesn't seem necessary on sublime.

Comment: btw I'm on Mac and the ctrl+ doesn't work

Comment: `ctrl + \`` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Sublime Text use a particular syntax for Reg Expr that slightly differs from the one used in coding. 
In my specific circumstance, to find a domain in a string using a greedy expression including the carriage return (useful to clean a huge amount of rubbish in an SEO backlinks spreadsheet) I ended up using the following.

```
.*://leaderlive.co.uk/.*\n
```

Dots doesn't require escaping ... no need to add the end of string ^$ ... it simply works and I didn't spend time investigating the reasons.